# Using specific value of integer variable from TextEdit response in MainActivity, to use in a different class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I'm attempting to code an app that takes the users numerical specifications from the main activity in the form of a `TextEdit` input, convert that to an integer and then use that *specific value* of the integer and use that value in a separate class file which I will use the result of the class in the main activity.

Is this possible? Here's what I've attempted in the global variables of the main activity:

```
deadzoneValue = findViewById(R.id.TextView_deadzoneInfo);
public EditText threshold, deadzone;

public String deadzoneString = deadzone.getText().toString(); //deadzone being the name of the 
public int timeLimit = Integer.parseInt(deadzoneString);

public String thresholdString = threshold.getText().toString();
public static int thresholdLimit = Integer.parseInt(thresholdString);
```

I'm not sure how to use these in the `Deadzone` class, which I'm trying to take the *specific value* and use there.

**EDIT**: `Deadzone.java` isn't an `activity` but a `class` with functions that are called in the `MainActivity`.

Comment: 1-Use singletone class for defining of global parameters (with any type) and then get it in any location of you code 2-Also you can use "put" for sending simple data from an activity to another.

Answer (score 0):

Using of ClassicSingleton:

```
public class ClassicSingleton2 {
private static String instance = null;

protected ClassicSingleton2() {

}

public static String getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public static void setInstance(String instance) {
    ClassicSingleton2.instance = instance;
}
```

}

You could change type of instance variable to int ...
And in target code you could get this data:

```
xRef = ClassicSingleton2.getInstance();
```

This is very simple.

2:
And using of put (putExtra)

```
Intent oI = new Intent((FirstActivity)this,SecondActivity.class);
            oI.putExtra("XRefCaller",123);
```

And in target code(activity) :

```
Bundle oBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(oBundle != null){
        oXRefCaller = oBundle.getString("XRefCaller",-1);
        //checking with -1 if the parameter does not exist or is null 
    }
```

Comment: Would this work if the ```Deadzone``` class isn't an ```activity``` but rather a class which functions are enacted in? Functions called in the ```MainActivity```?

Comment: If you has a problem with accessing of your main activity in your class , you could pass your activity or your context to your class when calling the class method. and then in your class method , change your main activity parameters or control values(Changes from your class the main activity components ...)